# Why static fields are not initialized in time?

Tags: java, static, null, nullpointerexception

The following code prints `null` once.

```
class MyClass {
   private static MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
   private static final Object obj = new Object();
   public MyClass() {
      System.out.println(obj);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Why are the static objects not initialized before the constructor runs?

**Update**

I'd just copied this example program without attention, I thought we were talking about 2 Object fields, now I saw that the first is a MyClass field.. :/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Because statics are initialized in the order they are given in source code.

Check this out:

```
class MyClass {
  private static MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
  private static MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass();
  public MyClass() {
    System.out.println(myClass);
    System.out.println(myClass2);
  }
}
```

That will print:

```
null
null
myClassObject
null
```

**EDIT**

Ok let's draw this out to be a bit more clear.

1. Statics are initialized one by one in the order as declared in the source code.
2. Since the first static is initialized before the rest, during its initialization the rest of the static fields are null or default values.
3. During the initiation of the second static the first static is correct but the rest are still null or default.

Is that clear?

**EDIT 2**

As Varman pointed out the reference to itself will be null while it is being initialized.  Which makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: ..and because `myClass` **itself** is static.

Comment: ok, static is initilized in order. And the statics are before the constructor, so why it is not initialized when the constructor runs?
Really looks like a bug for me..

Comment: @Tom, nope you got it wrong.

statics are not before constructors. statics are init when constructors are called respectively.  In my example when the first static is init with MyClass the constructor is called.  When the constructor is running myClass is init (because its running itself), but myClass2 is not.  When the second MyClass is init it calls the constructor again and this time myClass was already init and myClass2 is being init at that time

Comment: so its like statics are initialized in another thread while the constructor runs? Do you have a link to same text explaining this in details?

Comment: Updated post, I hope that is more explanatory

Comment: I am also surprised you are the first one to ask this question so simply.  This is ones of those gotchas

Comment: @Pyrolistical : When I executed your program I got different result. It printed `null  null  myClassObjectref  null`

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  Almost 2 years after this question was answered and you are the first to actually run this code?  I'll fix the answer

Answer (score 28):

Let's try a different way to explain this...

This is the sequence the JVM goes through when you first reference the class `MyClass`.

1. Load the byte-code into memory.
2. Memory for the static storage is cleared (binary zero).
3. Initialize the class:

   4. Execute each static initializer in the order that it appears, this includes static variables and `static { ... }` blocks.
   5. JVM then initializes your `myClass` static variable to a new instance of `MyClass`.
   6. When this happens, the JVM notices that `MyClass` is already loaded (byte-code) **and in the process of being initialized**, so it skips initialization.
   7. Allocate memory on heap for object.
   8. Execute constructor.
   9. Print out value of `obj` which is still `null` (since it is not part of the heap and constructor initialized variables).
   10. When constructor finishes, execute next static initializer which sets `obj` to a new instance of `Object`.
4. Class initialization done. From this point, all constructor calls will behave as you presume/expect - that is `obj` would not be `null` but a reference to an `Object` instance.

Remember that Java specifies that a `final` variable is assigned a value once. It is not that it is guaranteed to be assigned a value when the code references it unless you ensure that the code references it after it is assigned.

This is not a bug. This is the defined way to handle usage of the class during its own initialization. If this were not so, then the JVM would go into an infinite loop. See step #3.3 (if the JVM does not skip initialization for a class that is in the process of initialization it would just keep initializing it - infinite loop).

Note as well, this all happens on the same thread that first references the class. Second, the JVM guarantees that initialization will complete before any other thread is allowed to use this class.

Comment: Nice answer Kevin, best one here

Comment: You mean it skips "static" initialization, I suppose.

Answer (score 19):

That's because Java executes the static section in order it is declared. In your case, the sequence is

1. new MyClass
2. new Object

When #1 is executed, obj is still not initialized, so it prints null. Try the following and you will see the difference:

```
class MyClass {
  private static final Object obj = new Object();
  private static MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
  public MyClass() {
    System.out.println(obj); // will print null once
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, it is better to avoid such a construct all together. If you are trying to create a singleton, that's how that code fragment should look like:

```
class MyClass {

  private static final MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

  private Object obj = new Object();

  private MyClass() {
    System.out.println(obj); // will print null once
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct about the <clinit> execution order. The Singleton isn't really a Singleton though, since the constructor is public.

Comment: ok, static is initilized in order. And the statics are declared and asked for initialize before the constructor, so why it is not initialized when the constructor runs?
Really looks like a bug for me..

Comment: @Tom you have to understand by calling `new MyClass()` in the static you ARE calling the constructor

Comment: think we are having a communication fail here. I actually know that new MyClass() is a call to a constructor, this does not explain why the static fields are null when the constructor runs. Like the instance fields are initialized before the constructor, the static fields should be either.. but why they don't?

Comment: Static members *are* constructed before the instance constructor runs. It's just that in your code, your static initializer *also* calls your constructor. It's a chicken-and-egg problem.

Answer (score 0):

that is because static fields initialized in same order they defined.

Comment: this does not answer why it is null at constructor time.

Answer (score 0):

@Pyrolistical

since the initial of first static field myclass is not fully constructed ...the result i get is

null
null
testInitialize.MyObject@70f9f9d8
null