# How static methods and variables gets initialized in java memory system?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, static-methods, static-variables

I'm confused about this part in java -

During java classloader system loads the class file it allocates memory for different variables and methods present in the class file - like for new object memory gets allocated during runtime . But in case of static variables and methods in the class how and when memory gets allocated  ? - Please help.

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-static-variables-are-initialized-in-java).

Comment: Static context is initialized when a class is loaded for the first time. It is clearly stated in every decent Java book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where is a static method and a static variable stored in java. In heap or in stack memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta)

Answer (score 0):

The memory is allocated when the `classloader` loads the `class`. It's a shared memory space accessible by all the instance of the `class` and the class itself. Therefore unsafe to use a `static` variable in `multithreading` environment. Solution to `static` variable in `multithreading` environment is to make it `final` as well.