# When static variable be instantiated in Android

Tags: java, android

For example, I have a class

```
public class EagerInitializedSingleton {
        private static final EagerInitializedSingleton instance = new EagerInitializedSingleton();

        public static EagerInitializedSingleton getInstance(){
            return instance;
        }
}
```

And my application have 2 activity A.java and B.java (from A I can go to B).
In B activity I have

```
import EagerInitializedSingleton.java;

public class B{
     onCreate(...){
         EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()...
     }
}
```

My question is when `instantiated` be instantiated`

- When launch application (before A Activity start)
- When import `EagerInitializedSingleton.java`
- Or when EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()

If possible, can I check when be instantiated by write Log or something?
Any help would be great appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I'm follow here to create `EagerInitializedSingleton`
http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples
And they have say

> If your singleton class is not using a lot of resources, this is the
>   approach to use. But in most of the scenarios, Singleton classes are
>   created for resources such as File System, Database connections etc
>   and we should avoid the instantiation until unless client calls the
>   getInstance method

Like some answer say that `instance` be instantiated when I call `EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()...`, so who is correct?

Comment: for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-static-variables-are-initialized-in-java

Comment: create a private, no parameter `EagerInitializedSingleton` constructor and call your `Log.d` there

Comment: @pskink please check my update, if you don't mind please give me an explain

Comment: The process of making your class **Singleton**, as above, is not correct. Each time you call **EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()** a new instance of your class will be returned.

Comment: see Vucko's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` variables are initialized when the classloader loads the class for the first time, either through static reference or instance creation. It will be shared across all instances of the class. And remember, it will be initialized before any instance creation of the class.

So, in your question:

> When launch application (before Activity start)

No

> When import `EagerInitializedSingleton.java`

No

> When EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()

Yes

Or whenever you make a static reference to the `EagerInitializedSingleton` class.

**Edit** - Just to clear things out as per comments:

Call to `getInstance()` **will not** result in instance creation. But the **`static` reference** to the class does as the class loads for the first time.

Comment: when he calls `EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()` only `instance` varaiable is returned, nothing else

Comment: `Static fields are initialized when the class is loaded by the class loader. Default values are assigned at this time. This is done in the order than they appear in the source code.`

Comment: @pskink, yes instance will be returned but `new EagerInitializedSingleton()` will be called first.

Comment: but it will not be called as a result of `getInstance` method call

Comment: @pskink, yes I have suggested the same thing in my answer. :) I am not saying that singleton implementation is correct. I am just trying answer when the instance will be created.

Comment: so it will be created when the class is loaded by the class loader, not `When EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()` gets called

Comment: @pskink, I agree to what you are pointing. That `getInstance()` method **will not** create instance. I am saying that `static` reference to the class **before** actually invoking the method will result in instance creation.

Comment: @RohitArya please help me one more, can you explain why the OP of  journal dev say `we should avoid the instantiation until unless client calls the getInstance method`

Comment: Yes, they have pointed it right. In that case, all resources should be instantiated (by calling new SomeClass()) inside (say) a private constructor of the singleton class. and thus when we invoke getInstance method, it will call the private constructor to initialize those. But if you create some static variables like the one in the question, they will get initialized even with static reference of the class. So basically, it's all dependent on the implementation of singletons.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance()`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this is **not a proper singleton** implementation. Your constructor, or lack of one, will allow the user to use the default empty constructor and create more objects of that class. Check out how to implement it [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)  or anywhere you find online.

The question you asked has nothing to do with android, it's a plain Java question, having to do with `static` variables initialization. You can find the answer to that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-static-variables-are-initialized-in-java).

Comment: thank you. I visit this link but still confusing, please check my update. Does the owner of the link correct or @Rohit Arya answer is correct

Comment: @pskink like the java link they say `static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution`. does execution here mean when application start

Comment: Owner of the link explains **generally** and Rohit answers your question. And he has answered your particular question. I am just telling you that you need to fix your implementation of singleton, and then you will not even have this question (because it's not a proper way to initialize the instance there anyway).

Comment: yes, @Vucko is right. This is not a proper way of creating singletons. But I answered when the instance will actually be created. :)

Comment: I don't ask about how to create the singleton, I just ask when instance variable is initialized :(

Comment: @PhanVanLinh, yes then you can refer my answer. :)

Comment: if you don't mind, please check my update in my question. in there it have this sentence `we should avoid the instantiation until unless client calls the getInstance method`. So with @RohitArya answer, this sentence is completely wrong right?