# About Java function calling

Tags: java, function, methods

Could someone explain to me when I run this code, I don't get the Sysout statement until I enter my first keyboard input?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class test1{

            static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            static int k = scan.nextInt();

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                setK();
                System.out.println(" K is: " + k);
        }
            public static void setK(){
                System.out.println("Please input K value");
                k = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when static variables are initialized in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-static-variables-are-initialized-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` variables of your `test1` class are initialized before your `main` method is executed. This happens when the class is initialized.

Therefore the

```
static int k = scan.nextInt();
```

statement is executed before your `main` method and waits for input. Only after the input is entered, `main` starts running and calls `setK();`, which prints "Please input K value".

I'm not sure this was intentional, since your `setK()` method seems to be the method that should read the input and assign it to k. Therefore, change your code to :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1{

        static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        static int k;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            setK();
            System.out.println(" K is: " + k);
    }
        public static void setK(){
            System.out.println("Please input K value");
            k = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
static int k = scan.nextInt();
```

runs during class initialization. It blocks and waits for input of an integer.

This code runs before `main` because it is a `static` initialization. It must be complete before the first method of the class is called. At that point `k` has the first value you have entered. After that, `main` calls `setK`, prompting for another input.

You can fix this by removing initialization (i.e. the `= scan.nextInt();` part) from declaration of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the behaviour you expect would be as follows:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int k;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please input K value");
        k = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" K is: " + k);
    }
}
```

BTW, you should stick to Java naming conventions.

Comment: Could you explain more by what you mean as Java naming conventions?

Comment: @911DidBush, ahh thanks. I thought I was doing something wrong so I asked. I've had a read and will try to go along with those - thank you.

Comment: Your title mention "functions". Since Java 8, the "function" term refers to the target for a lambda expression or method reference (see [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)).

And the name of your class is supposed to be mixed-case (see [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))