# java Object null after instance and calling inside method

Tags: java, sqlmap

can anyone help me with this issue, i'm working with java using SQLMap(ibatis).
i have 3 class which is MainConfiguration, SQLMap, DBUtility.

1. Main Configuration (this class is using to set an object inside SQLMap class)

```
public class MainConfiguration
{
     public static String file = "configuration/db/SQLMapConfig.conf";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
        new MainConfiguration().loadConfiguration();    
     }  

     public static void loadConfiguration()
     {
        SQLMap.setMapFile(file);
        List list = DBUtility.loadUsers();
     }
}
```

2. SQL Map (this class is the getter and setter of and object)

```
public final class SQLMap
{
    private static SqlMapClient sqlMap;

    public static void setMapFile(String sMapFile)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlMap = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(new FileReader(sMapFile));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing SqlMapClient class", e);
        }
    }

    public static SqlMapClient getSqlMapInstance()
    {
        return sqlMap;
    }
}
```

3. DBUtility (this class is where object instance and get object from SQLMap class)

   ```
   public class DBUtility
   {
   // object utility
   protected static SqlMapClient sqlMap = SQLMap.getSqlMapInstance();

   //constructor
   public DBUtility() throws Exception
   {
   }

   public static List loadUsers()
   {
       //it's working
       logger.info("SQLMap Get Instance = " + SQLMap.getSqlMapInstance());

       //it's not working
       logger.info("SQLMap Get Instance = " + sqlMap);

       //code below will be error because of null sqlMap
       try
       {
           listUser = sqlMap.queryForList("getUsers");
       }
       catch (Exception sqle)
       {
           logger.error("Error on load all user", sqle);
       }
       return listUser;
   }
   }
   ```

the logger give me this :

SQLMap Get Instance = com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl@76707e36

SQLMap Get Instance = null

how come the second log give me null, even i have instance the object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are static variables are initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-are-static-variables-are-initialized) Your field `sqlMap` is initialized when the `DBUtility` class is loaded, which apparently happens before `SQLMap.setMapFile(file);` is called. So, `sqlMap` points at different things: `null` in the static field, and an actual instance when you call the getter in `loadUsers()`.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE. More specifically, show us the entire program including the main() method, or at least the method that wraps the entire problem together.

Comment: Maybe the initialization was executed too early (before the call to `setMapFile`).

Comment: hello guys, i've update my code. i'm calling that DBUtility class in MainConfiguration class.

Comment: And does it work?

Comment: @MalteHartwig nope, it's still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field `sqlMap` is initialized when the DBUtility class is loaded, which apparently happens before `SQLMap.setMapFile(file);` is called. So, `sqlMap` points at different things: `null` in the static field, and an actual instance when you call the getter in `loadUsers()`.

The problem is that `DBUtility` looks up the `sqlMap` too early. It has to wait until the `file` is passed to `SQLMap`. Change your code like this to delay the initialization of `DbUtility.sqlMap`:

```
public static void loadConfiguration()
{
    SQLMap.setMapFile(file);
    DBUtility.initMapClient();  // notify DBUtility
    List list = DBUtility.loadUsers();
}

public class DBUtility
{
    protected static SqlMapClient sqlMap;  // do not initialize too early

    public static void initMapClient()
    {
        sqlMap = SQLMap.getSqlMapInstance();  // wait for SQLMap to be ready
    }
```

Of course, it would be simpler if you did not even have the `sqlMap` field in DBUtility. Just call `SQLMap.getSqlMapInstance()` every time you need it. This is especially important in case the instance ever changes:

```
listUser = SQLMap.getSqlMapInstance().queryForList("getUsers");
```

Read [When are static variables are initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-are-static-variables-are-initialized) for a more detailed explanation of static fields.