# @PropertySource @Value static strings return null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, appsettings

int Activation and int ForgotPassword works good but string variables return null i need static class for AppSettings

```
@PropertySource("classpath:appSettings.properties")
    public class AppSettings {

        @Value("${Activation}")
        private static int Activation;
        @Value("${ForgotPassword}")
        private static int ForgotPassword;
        @Value("${CryptoSplit}")
        private static String CryptoSplit;
        @Value("${CryptoKey}")
        private static String CryptoKey;

        public static String getCryptoSplit() {
            return CryptoSplit;
        }

        public static String getCryptoKey() {
            return CryptoKey;
        }
        public static int getActivation() {
            return Activation;
        }

        public static int getForgotPassword() {
            return ForgotPassword;
        }

    }
```

.properties

```
Activation=0
ForgotPassword=1
CryptoSplit=:OSK:
CryptoKey=TheBestSecretKey
```

Comment: write setter methods and put `@Value` on setter methods instead of putting on variables

Comment: You cannot auto wire or use `@Value` on `static` fields/methods .

Comment: If you want to define a static variable using value annotation have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192557/3493036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not support `@Value` injection on **static** fields.

Are you sure that you definitely **require** a "static class for AppSettings"? I suspect that might represent a misunderstanding of how Spring singletons work.

If, however, you have a genuine need for a "static class for AppSettings" then you *can* achieve this as follows:

```
@Value("${CryptoKey}")
public void setCryptoKey(String cryptoKey) {
    AppSettings.CryptoKey = CryptoKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Value() gets called on the initialization of the bean , the bean gets initialized on need not on the startup so you will not have the value unless the bean is initialized