# Spring Boot application to read a value from properties file in main method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to get the value of a property

```
hello.world=Hello World
```

in MainApp class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
}
```

This didn't work as its the main method.

```
@Value("${hello.world}")
public static String helloWorld;
```

Maybe its possible to load by

```
  Properties prop = new Properties();

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

Is there any other better way to get the properties using Spring in the main method of SpringBoot before  SpringApplication.run

Comment: Why do you need this information before context runs?

Answer (score 9):

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = 
           SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
String str = ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("some.prop");
System.out.println("=>>>> " + str);
```

Comment: After this again we have to call app.run(args) to start the application?

Comment: We usually call `run()` method to start spring boot application. `run()` returns `ConfigurableApplicationContext` which in turn can return `ConfigurableEnvironment` that contain method to pull properties. To verify see your `SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args)` statement, it will also be returning `ConfigurableApplicationContext`.

Comment: What if we I have to get before SpringApplication.run ?

Comment: When we call `SpringApplication.run()` then it starts tasks like auto-wiring dependency etc. Before that with the help of spring we can't fetch any property, to make this happen you have to read properties file manually. Can you please specify what is the use-case that you want to read property before `run()` invoking method?

Comment: Then I believe you have to follow manual process that you have mentioned earlier to load properties file and read it.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared the variable helloWorld as static. Hence you need to use Setter Injection and not Field Injection.

Injecting a static non-final field is a bad practice. Hence Spring doesn't allow it. But you can do a workaround like this.

```
public static String helloWorld;

      @Value("${hello.world}")
        public void setHelloWorld(String someStr) {
          helloWorld = someStr
        }
```

You can access this variable helloWorld at any point in the class, if its any other class. But if you want to do it in the main class. You can access the variable only after this line

`SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);)`

i.e only after the application has started.

Comment: of course it works. Only thing is we can access the variable only after `SpringApplication.run(....)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. Its better to use [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html).
Thanks to this you can have a non static method that Spring Boot will run for you automatically:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimulatorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Value("${my-value}")
private myValue;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SimulatorApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  // here you can access my-value
}
```

}

Comment: To have Spring Boot get property my-value from application.properties use 
    @Value(${my-value})
    myValue
Not, as you have it 
    @Value("myvalue")
    myValue
which means 
    String myValue = "my-value";

Comment: Thank you @NetDawg, fixed in above answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MainApp.class);
     springApplication.addListeners(new VersionLogger());
     springApplication.run(args);
}


// The VersionLogger Class
public class VersionLogger implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>{

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent applicationEvent) {
    String helloWorld = applicationEvent.getEnvironment().getProperty("hello.world");
  }
}
```

**ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent**
Event published when a SpringApplication is starting up and the Environment is first available for inspection and modification.

Answer (score 1):

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

String applicationPropertyVersion=applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("application.property.version");

    LOGGER.info("RELEASE CODE VERSION {} and applicationProperty Version {} ", LcoBuildVersion.version,
            applicationPropertyVersion);
```

Comment: Hi Vishal. Thanks for your answer. Usually it's useful to provide a few words to explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can't read values into static fields . Here is the explanation  gives a better insight [How to assign a value from application.properties to a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable)