# How to resolve spring boot @Value and store it in another string?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

```
@Value("${db.schema.name}")
private String dbSchemaName;

private final String QUERY = 
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM " + dbSchemaName + ".product "  +
        "WHERE id = :id";
```

I use the static String "Query" for multiple methods. The variable dbSchemaName is defined in application.properties (db.schema.name).

```
public List<Object> loadData(final String id){
   final MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
   parameters.addValue("id", id);
   return jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY, parameters, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<>(mapper)));
}
```

If i execute the Method loadData(...), the dbSchemaName will not be resolved.

If i change the Query from a String variable to a method, the dbSchemaName will be resolved correctly.

```
private final getQuery(){
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM " + dbSchemaName + ".product "  +
        "WHERE id = :id";
}
```

but I want to get Access of dbSchemaName in the Query String. For me dbSchemaName is always null in the *private final String QUERY*. Or is there better design than making it a method?

Comment: Instead of field injection use setter injection to inject to static fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign a value from application.properties to a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable)

Comment: I have edit my post.

Comment: I have updated my post. I don't want to make it static, i want want to get Access of dbSchemaName in the Query String. dbSchemaName is always null

Comment: you have access to the value in any method with the annotation `@PostConstruct` ...

Answer (score 0):

In your non-working code sample java constructs the `QUERY` string before Spring has injected the value of `${db.schema.name}` into `dbSchemaName` and it is, therefore, `null`.

Either stick to your method example or inject the whole query from properties:

```
@Value("${db.query.value}")
private String query;
```

Where `db.query.value` is:

```
SELECT * FROM ${db.schema.name}.product WHERE id = :id
```