# @Value in spring boot is not working. It is loading from Environment object but not field injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

environment properties are there in application.properties

application.properties

```
app.mail.allowedDomains=gmail
```

in class

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Value("${app.mail.allowedDomains}")
private static String allowedDomainsForMail;

@Value("${app.mail.allowedDomains:nothing}")
private static String allowedDomainsForMail2;

public void printProperties() {
    System.out.println("Inside impl");
    System.out.println("@Value:\t" + allowedDomainsForMail);
    System.out.println("@Value:\t" + allowedDomainsForMail2);
    System.out.println("Env:\t" + env.getProperty("app.mail.allowedDomains"));
}
```

Output

Inside impl

```
@Value: null
@Value: null
Env:    gmail
```

It is not even setting "nothing"(default value if not found) in 2nd scenario. But from env it's printing

I even tried with @ConfigurationProperties in main class of package.

No success.

Is value fetched from env file on each hit or on app load only it will load?

Value from org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

Comment: The problem is the use of static fields.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring does not allow inject into a static field. Overall it's considered not a good practice. Below a few links which might help you to understand why.

[link#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable/45193356)
[link#2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364496/are-spring-beans-declared-as-static-a-poor-design-choice)

Remove static and the injection should happen, since the env `Environment` was injected.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring doesn't support static field injection. Also @Value annotation is also not the best practice.

The best way is to use @ConfigurationProperties annotation and bind it with application properties. It will help you to mock Configration Bean in Unit tests, instead of use reflection for @Value injection

Comment: can you share any link related to what you are saying? Just wanna explore

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot