# Spring: Inject a value into a statically accessed class

Tags: java, spring

Consider the following class:

```
public class ExpressionTokenClassifier {

  private static final String       PROMQL_KEYWORDS = "promql-keywords.json";
  private static final List<String> KEYWORDS;

  static {
    List<PromQLKeyword> words = KeywordsExtractor.extractKeywords(PROMQL_KEYWORDS);
    KEYWORDS = words.stream().map(PromQLKeyword::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static void classifyTokens(List<ExpressionToken> tokens) {
    ... // KEYWORDS is used in here
  }

}
```

Notice the hardwired file name (`PROMQL_KEYWORDS`) specified and used in the static initialization block. This works, but I would like to remove the hardcoded value and instead use dependency injection (Spring) to set the value from `application.yaml`. **This class is intended to only be used statically.**

My research indicates that the Spring framework does not allow setting a static field with the `@Value` annotation. I have seen some suggestions of a workaround, but do not understand how they would work. Here is an example where I attempted to do this:

```
@Component
public class ExpressionTokenClassifier2 {

  private static final List<String> KEYWORDS;

  private static String             KEYWORDS_FILE;

  @Value("${app.keywords-file}")
  public void setKeywordsFileName(String name) {
    KEYWORDS_FILE = name;
  }

  static {
    List<PromQLKeyword> words = KeywordsExtractor.extractKeywords(KEYWORDS_FILE);
    KEYWORDS = words.stream().map(PromQLKeyword::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static void classifyTokens(List<ExpressionToken> tokens) {
    ... // KEYWORDS is used in here
  }

}
```

When I tried it, the application fails to start because of NPE (`KEYWORDS_FILE` is null). My immediate question is: *Where and when would the `setKeywordsFileName()` method be called?* Nowhere, as far as I can tell - and the results agree. Am I missing some logic?

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? I could change this class so that it's instantiated instead of statically accessed, but the class that uses this class is **also** a statically accessed class. I really don't want to have to change a bunch of code to fix this.

**UPDATE**:

Upon further investigation, it appears that this is essentially not doable, at least not without a lot of extra work that probably defeats the purpose. This link, to me, describes the situation quite well.

[How to assign a value from application.properties to a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable)

Looks like I'm going to have to think about this for awhile.

Comment: The static block will be executed before the constructor, which results in the NPE, so could move the static code to the constructor.  But since it's now a Component, it probably should not have any static methods.  But if it really does need to have static methods, then perhaps create an @Configuration class that receives the @Value, and sets the value in the `ExpressionTokenClassifier2` via a static setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a `@Component` and `@PostConstruct` method for init task:

Spring conponent is singleton, so no need for static.

```
@Component // singleton
public class ExpressionTokenClassifier {
    
    @Value("${app.keywords-file}")
    private String file;

    private List<String> KEYWORDS;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       [...]
    }

}
```

if static access is essential, you can init your static class as soon as the application is started:

```
public class ExpressionTokenClassifier {
    
    private List<String> KEYWORDS;

    static void init(String file) {
        List<PromQLKeyword> words = KeywordsExtractor.extractKeywords(file);
        KEYWORDS = words.stream().map(PromQLKeyword::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
     public static void classifyTokens(List<ExpressionToken> tokens) {
        // KEYWORDS is used in here
    }

}

@Component
public class ExpressionTokenClassifierInitializer {
    
    @Value("${app.keywords-file}")
    private String file;

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationStartedEvent() {
       ExpressionTokenClassifier.init(file);
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, but then how do I inject this class into the statically called invoking class?

Comment: try to eliminate the static accesses completely. just @Inject ExpressionTokenClassifier where you need. spring will create one instance and use it everywhere you are injecting it.

Comment: That means I need to make the calling class non-statically invoked as well. Not what I wanted to do.

Comment: Yeah, no. This will have major repercussions. Not doing that.

Comment: @JosephGagnon I have edited my answer and added a second suggestion.