# Why openai key is not working in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openai-api

```
@Service
public class OpenAITranslationService {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public OpenAITranslationService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public OpenAIResponse translate(String language, String text) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(OpenAIConstants.AUTHORIZATION, OpenAIConstants.TOKEN);

        OpenAIRequest ai = new OpenAIRequest();
        ai.setModel(OpenAIConstants.MODEL);
        ai.setPrompt(OpenAIConstants.TRANSLATE + language + ": " + text);
        ai.setFrequency_penalty(0);
        ai.setPresence_penalty(0);
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(ai, headers);

        ResponseEntity<OpenAIResponse> data = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", HttpMethod.POST, entity, OpenAIResponse.class);
        return data.getBody();
    }
}
```

```
@Value("${api.key}")
    public static final String API_KEY = "";

    public static final String TOKEN = "Bearer " + API_KEY;
```

```
@PostMapping("/translate")
    public List<String> translate(@RequestParam String language, @RequestParam String text) {
        OpenAIResponse response = service.translate(language, text);
        return response.getChoicesList().stream().map(Choices::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

API key is defined as `api.key` in `application.properties` file. I send the request but response code is 401. Where could there be a mistake?

I tried to create a new API key but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a copy of this:
[How to assign a value from application.properties to a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192373/how-to-assign-a-value-from-application-properties-to-a-static-variable)

Here is a janky solution that I would not recommend: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field

Best use the accepted solution from the stackoverflow question itself. It nicely explains why its bad to inject values onto a static variable and what you can actually do.