# static object vs constructor, why constructor executed firstly and assigned in static reference variable

Tags: java, constructor, static

```
public class testing {
    static testing tmp = new testing();

    testing() {
        System.out.println("You are good");
    }

    public static void main(String... str) {

    }
}
```

---

In the above code 'You are good' is printed. But I want to know why this happened as constructor is non static method and static variables execute before not static methods.

Comment: `static testing tmp = new testing();` calls the constructor. And `testing` is static...

Answer (score 0):

The static variables initialize when class loads for the first time. In your case the static variable is referring to the constructor of the same class so the cunstructor is called. Which then prints the statement `System.out.println("You are good");` .
Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-are-static-variables-initialized)

The statement will not print if:

```
// 1. Non-static declaration
testing tmp = new testing();

// 2. Initialization skipped - no call to constructor
testing tmp2 = null; //new testing();
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the static variable `tmp` uses the constructor to initialize a new instance of `testing`. It doesn't matter that the constructor is technically a non-static (instance) method if it gets called inside the declaration of a static variable.

More precisely, the static variables of a class are initialized at some point during loading the class definition. This is completely independent of any calls to static or instance method later on in the code.