# Java mockito test static method keeps the mock from the first testcase in runs

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to create multipele testcases with Mockito in Java with static mocks. They run fine when running seperate but when I run the whole test class the mocked method which ran first (in this case shouldRequirePricingIfSucceeding) will also impact the other testcases (in this case shouldNotRequirePricingIfRequestFails will never fail). I have tried now to just put all the things I mock even in their own test methods but even that doesnt work. Here is my code:

```
public class PricingService {
    public static final int PRODUCT_CODE = 10;
    private final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PricingService.class);
    private static final PricingOauthApi pricingOauthApi = PricingOauthApiFactory.create();
    private static final PricingApi pricingApi = PricingApiFactory.create();
    private final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");

    public boolean requiresPricingBeforeSendPush(PushCSCTransaction pushCSCTransaction) {
        int transactionType = pushCSCTransaction.getCscTransaction().getTransactionType();
        if (!pushCSCTransaction.getControlArea().getSource().equals("TEST") ||
            transactionType != 30 &&
                transactionType != 31)
            return false;

        boolean sendRequestSuccessfully = sendPriceRequest(pushCSCTransaction);

        return sendRequestSuccessfully && transactionType == 31;
    }

    private boolean sendPriceRequest(PushCSCTransaction pushCSCTransaction) {
        try {
            OauthRequest oauthRequest = new OauthRequest(Configuration.Pricing.getOauthScope(), Configuration.Pricing.getOauthClientId(), Configuration.Pricing.getOauthClientSecret());
            Response<OauthResponse> oauthResponse = pricingOauthApi.oauth(oauthRequest, Configuration.Pricing.getOauthPathId()).execute();

            if (!oauthResponse.isSuccessful() || oauthResponse.body() == null) throw new WebApplicationException("");

            Response<Void> response = pricingApi.pricing(pushCSCTransaction, "Bearer " + oauthResponse.body().getAccessToken()).execute();

            return response.isSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Error when trying to send transaction message", exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PricingServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldNotRequirePricingIfRequestFails() throws IOException {
        PricingApi pricingApi = mock();
        PricingOauthApi pricingOauthApi = mock();
        try (MockedStatic<PricingApiFactory> pricingApiFactory = Mockito.mockStatic(PricingApiFactory.class);
             MockedStatic<PricingOauthApiFactory> pricingOauthApiFactory = Mockito.mockStatic(PricingOauthApiFactory.class)) {
            pricingApiFactory.when(PricingApiFactory::create).thenReturn(pricingApi);
            pricingOauthApiFactory.when(PricingOauthApiFactory::create).thenReturn(pricingOauthApi);
            Call<OauthResponse> call = mock(Call.class);
            Mockito.when(pricingOauthApi.oauth(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(call);
            Mockito.when(call.execute()).thenThrow(new IOException("Test"));

            PushCSCTransaction transaction = createCsvTransaction("TEST", 31, PRODUCT_CODE, 1312, 311, 1);
            PricingService service = new PricingService();

            boolean result = service.requiresPricingBeforeSendPush(transaction);

            assertFalse(result);
            Mockito.verify(pricingOauthApi).oauth(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
            Mockito.verify(pricingApi, Mockito.never()).pricing(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRequirePricingIfSucceeding() throws IOException {
        PricingApi pricingApi = mock();
        PricingOauthApi pricingOauthApi = mock();
        try (MockedStatic<PricingApiFactory> pricingApiFactory = Mockito.mockStatic(PricingApiFactory.class);
             MockedStatic<PricingOauthApiFactory> pricingOauthApiFactory = Mockito.mockStatic(PricingOauthApiFactory.class)) {
            pricingApiFactory.when(PricingApiFactory::create).thenReturn(pricingApi);
            Call<Void> call = mock(Call.class);
            Mockito.when(pricingApi.pricing(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(call);
            Mockito.when(call.execute()).thenReturn(Response.success(null));

            pricingOauthApiFactory.when(PricingOauthApiFactory::create).thenReturn(pricingOauthApi);
            Call<OauthResponse> callOauth = mock(Call.class);
            Mockito.when(pricingOauthApi.oauth(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(callOauth);
            OauthResponse oauthResponse = new OauthResponse();
            Mockito.when(callOauth.execute()).thenReturn(Response.success(oauthResponse));

            PushCSCTransaction transaction = createCsvTransaction("TEST", 31, PRODUCT_CODE, 1312, 311, 1);
            PricingService service = new PricingService();

            boolean result = service.requiresPricingBeforeSendPush(transaction);

            assertTrue(result);
            Mockito.verify(pricingOauthApi).oauth(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
            Mockito.verify(pricingApi).pricing(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        }
    }
}
```

So when I run this code I get now always a true from sendPriceRequest since the mock will never change to throw a exception. What am I forgetting to unmock static methods? I am using Java 8 with mockito version 4.11.0 and junit 5.

Also tried adding:

```
@BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        Mockito.clearAllCaches();
    }
```

But that didnt work either.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @k314159 added the one I got. Some line numbers might not match since I removed some business logic from the service class

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping the NullPointException message would have more detail. If you were using Java 14 or later, it would have told you exactly which object was null. It could be `pricingOauthApi` or `Configuration` or `Configuration.Pricing` or whatever the `oauth()` call returned.

Comment: My hunch is that it might be caused by some interaction between the mocked statics in the two tests, especially pricingOauthApiFactory.

Comment: @k314159 saw it wrong it seems to keep the mock from the first testcase in future tests (had in other tests which I didnt include not added a implementation so that is why I had a nullexception). Only dont know what is required to unmock static methods since I thought the try catch implementation like this would auto solve that. Also clearAllCaches didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with mocking static methods.
Your `mockStatic` calls are correctly wrapped in try-with-resources blocks.

The problem is in your `PricingService` which uses static fields.
Static fields `pricingOauthApi` and `pricingApi` are initialized only once - when you create the first instance of your service.

Observe simpler example:

```java
class FooCollaborator {
}

class FooService {
    static FooCollaborator fooCollaborator = createFoo();

    static FooCollaborator createFoo() {
        System.out.println("static createFoo called");
        return new FooCollaborator();
    }

}


public class StaticTest {
    @Test
    void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
        FooService fooService = new FooService();
        System.out.println(fooService.fooCollaborator);
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2");
        FooService fooService = new FooService();
        System.out.println(fooService.fooCollaborator);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test1
static createFoo called
com.so.examples.mockito.FooCollaborator@327514f

test2
com.so.examples.mockito.FooCollaborator@327514f
```

- static field is initialized only once
- the initialization happens when the first instance of your service is created (thus, you have a chance to stub your static methods)

Typical pattern is not to hold the collaborators of your service in  static fields. Even better, pass them as constructor arguments (as an extra benefit, you wont need to mock static factory methods in your test).

Comment: Thought when I initialize a new service class that it would also initialize the statics for that class again

Comment: Nope - if you launch your tests in one process (most likely you do, as the default in jUnit is not to fork) java guarantees statics will be initialized only once.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704423/when-are-static-variables-initialized