# Java static fields

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are static fields open for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection)

If an object has a static reference in some class, will that object never be garbage collected? Also at what point will a static field be initialized?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this has been asked on SO multiple times. Since these are two questions, let's break it down:

Static variables are garbage collected when the ClassLoader through which they are loaded is electable for garbage collection. Check this post:
[Are static fields open for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection)

As for initialization, they are initialized once the class holding them is first loaded. Check this post also:
[Why static fields are not initialized in time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547713/why-static-fields-are-not-initialized-in-time)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if the forum is called SO because the same questions get asked SO many times. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A static field is initialised when the class is loaded.  It is available to be GCed when its class loader is unloaded.

Comment: At what point will it be unloaded?

Comment: When the ClassLoader is not referenced anywhere.  You will only see this for ClassLoaders you create.