# Java Calendar YEAR returning zero when beeing initialized to static int

Tags: java

I trying to understand the difference between the two lines below. Why is it returning a zero when I add static to the field.

```
private static final int this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

From this I get: `this_year = 0;`

```
private final int this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

And from this I get: `this_year = 2013;`

Someone who can explain why the first returns a zero?

Here's the code I use it in:

```
public class TheKing {
  public static final TheKing theKing = new TheKing();
  private final int beltSize;
  private static final int this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

  private TheKing() { 
    beltSize = this_year - 1930;
  }

  public int beltSize() {
    return beltSize;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("TheKing wears a size " + 
      theKing.beltSize() + " belt.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Both code blocks looks the same. Please organize your code in order to understand your problem.

Comment: `this_year = 2013` in both cases for me. How are you using the values elsewhere?

Comment: Other results than by @Vulcan. So far if used static, 2013 and all OK, non-static causes exception "referencing a non-static variable from static context" when I print it out.

Comment: I have Java-version "1.7.0_13"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fields are declared `static`, they are initialized in the static initialization method, meaning that your code looks like the following when compiled:

```
static {
    theKing = new TheKing();
    this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Notice that the constructor is called before `this_year` is initialized, and before an `int` is initialized, it has its default value of `0`.  In other words, `this_year` is used before it is set to `2013`.

One way to fix this is to simply reverse the order of the declarations:

```
private static final int this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
public static final TheKing theKing = new TheKing();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Static methods are initialized in the order they are given in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547737/1711796).

```
public static final TheKing theKing = new TheKing();
private static final int this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

So the above would initialize `theKing` first, which calls the constructor, which uses the uninitialized value of 0 of `this_year`. If you were to change it to:

```
private static final int this_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
public static final TheKing theKing = new TheKing();
```

it would work fine.

Or if you remove the `static`, `this_year` would get initialized as the object `theKing` is created.